# searching an External user in People picker and starting an invitation

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, people-picker, external-users, sharepoint-email

I am a junior Front-end developer. I want to know how can I search for non existing external users and sending them an email like the picture bellow

[image]

Here is my code

```
  <PeoplePicker
        context={porps.context as any}
        personSelectionLimit={3}
        groupName={""}
        onChange={_addUser}
        principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User, PrincipalType.SecurityGroup]}
        resolveDelay={200}
        defaultSelectedUsers={_Picker}
       
      />
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the site in question actually allows sharing with external users? Your screenshot looks like an OOB UI to me, but your ability to select external users is based on the sharing settings of the site (in Central Admin).

Comment: I want to write code to search for non-existing external user email for next step giving me this email as suggestion for sending them an invitation?
for example there is a functionality by Standard Sharepoint when you want to share the Sharepoint site with some non- existing external user (OOB UI)